# 'open' and 'csv.DictReader' cannot read file correctly

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a simple .csv file encoded in windows-1250. Two columns with key-value pairs, separated by semicolon. I would like to create a dictionary from this data. I used this solution: [How to read a .csv file into a dictionary in Python](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-read-a-%60.csv%60-file-into-a-dictionary-in-python). Code below:

```py
import os
import csv

strpath = r"C:\Project Folder"

filename = "to_dictionary.csv"

os.chdir(strpath)

test_csv = open(filename, mode="r", encoding="windows-1250")

dctreader = csv.DictReader(test_csv)

ordereddct = list(dctreader)[0]

finaldct = dict(ordereddct)

print(finaldct)
```

First of all, this file has 370 rows but I receive only **two**. Second, Python reads whole first row as a key and next row as a value (and then stops as I mentioned).

```py
# source data
# a;A
# b;B
# c;C
# ... up to 370 rows

# what I need (example; there should be 368 pairs more of course)
finaldct = {"a": "A", "b": "B"}

# what I receive
finaldct = {"a;A": "b;B"}
```

I have no idea why this happens and couldn't find any working solution.

Note: I would like to avoid using pandas because it seems to work slower in this case.

Answer (score 1):

*file has 370 rows but I receive only two*

This might be caused by problems with newlines (they do differ between systems, see [Newline wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) if you want to know more). [`csv` module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) suggest using `newline=''` i.e. in your case

```
test_csv = open(filename, newline='', mode="r", encoding="windows-1250")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a file with just two columns (assuming they're unquoted, etc.), you don't need use the `csv` module at all.

```
dct = {}
with open("file.txt", encoding="windows-1250") as f:
    for line in f:
        key, _, value = line.rstrip("\r\n").partition(";")
        dct[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below

```
data = dict()
with open('test.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        temp = line.strip()
        if temp:
            k,v = temp.split(';')
            data[k] = v
print(data)
```

test.csv

```
1;2
3;5
78;8
6;0
```

output

```
{'1': '2', '3': '5', '78': '8', '6': '0'}
```

Comment: This (a) reads the entire file into memory for no good reason (b) will break if there is more than one semicolon per line (which, granted, OP isn't saying they have) (c) strips all leading and trailing whitespace, not just newline characters

Comment: I agree about (a). About (b) - well.. this is not part of the question (multiple `;` in a line)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all but I finally managed to do so (and without looping)! The solution from Kite misleaded me a little. Here is my code:

```py
import os
import csv

strpath = r"C:\Project Folder"

filename = "to_dictionary.csv"

os.chdir(strpath)

test_csv = open(filename, mode="r", encoding="windows-1250")

csvreader = csv.reader(test_csv, delimiter=";")

finaldct = dict(csvreader)

print(finaldct)
```

So, I needed to specify delimiter first but in a reader. Second, there's no need to use `DictReader`. Changing reader to dictionary suffices.